# "Unexpected Error" on Join 2 simple tables

Tags: hadoop, hive, tableau-api, hortonworks-data-platform

I have created a hive database. I have created an ODBC Data source to Hive using Hortonworks ODBC Driver for Hive.

I use this data source from Tableau 9 (desktop).

I can query Table DimA, I can query Table FactA. But in tableau if I try to do a join I get error

```
[Hortonworks][HiveODBC] (35) Error from Hive: error code: '0' error message: 'ExecuteStatement finished with operation state: ERROR_STATE'.
Unexpected Error
```

I can easily go to my cluster and issue the same query in hiveshell without any problems and it returns results.

I searched the Internet and people have this permission problem which gets solved by "grant".. but in this case I am able to query individual 2 tables (dima, facta) easily from tableau... but ONLY when I JOIN the tables that it throws the above error.

I tried the "New Custom SQL" and copy pasted the SQL which worked in hive Shell... but tableau threw the error.

```
[Hortonworks][HiveODBC] (35) Error from Hive: error code: '40000' error message: 'Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:11 cannot recognize input near 'TOP' '1' '*' in select expression'.
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue. I had chosen the user "hue" to connect to HIVE.

I did this because a tutorial showed me the steps to connect to hive.

http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/how-to-install-and-configure-the-hortonworks-odbc-driver-on-windows-7/

but the tutorial is wrong in suggesting the user hue. they should instead use hdfs because hue user does not have rights to launch MR jobs which are required to run joins on Hive.

Answer (score 0):

Possible fix:

> This SQL error is a known issue when using Hadoop Hive driver 1.4.8 to
>   1.4.13. This issue can be resolved by rolling the client driver back to 1.3. The most recent drivers produce issues when using a CASE
>   statements in Tableau, and Hortonworks is in the process of repairing
>   this functionality. (http://community.tableau.com/thread/150002)